# drag and drop - lag in UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, drag-and-drop, lag

Hello drag and drop fans,

Can anyone explain why I see a long lag time when using drag and drop with my UWP apps?

I wrote a test app that contains just the drag and drop message handlers and also the pointer handlers for comparison. Here’s the code...

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        grid1.AllowDrop = true;
        grid1.DragOver += Grid1_DragOver;
        grid1.Drop += Grid1_Drop;
        grid1.DragLeave += Grid1_DragLeave;

        grid1.PointerEntered += Grid1_PointerEntered;
        grid1.PointerExited += Grid1_PointerExited;

    }

    //  Drag Handlers ************************
    private void Grid1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        msgFromPointer.Text = "  drag/drop item has entered";

        e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        Debug.WriteLine("in grid1 drag over handler");
    }

    private void Grid1_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        msgFromPointer.Text = "";
    }

    private void Grid1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("in grid1 drop handler");
    }


    // pointer handlers *******************
    private void Grid1_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        msgFromPointer.Text = "POINTER has entered";
    }

    private void Grid1_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        msgFromPointer.Text = "";
    }
```

When doing a drag and drop to my app, there seems to be about a 1/2 second delay before my app receives the dragOver message. In comparison, the pointerOver message seems to arrive almost simultaneously with the pointer movement. The slow behavior is the same when using the touch screen or a mouse. Here’s a video of the behavior…

[video of the laggy behavior](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Fw1ZS724iRtTD2cC9)

The PC I’m using has a touch screen and I’m wondering if there is some sort of touch “driver” or filter that is slowing down the drag and drop message. I've tried  a bunch of Windows config settings, like mouse and display settings, but no change. The PC is a Dell Inspiron 3593, with the latest drivers. My Windows 10 version is 1903, build 18362.836

The app I’m developing uses a lot of drag and drop and this slow behavior makes the user interface really difficult. It’s kind of like trying to conduct a phone conversation with a 1/2 second delay.

Any ideas?

Dan

Comment: it seems like the delay it takes to load up the thumbnail of the to the DragUI,
try again with a more cache-able file thumbnail, like the one of a .txt file,
also test what happens when you drag over multiple files.

Comment: I tried dropping a .txt file and multiple files, but got the same lag. In the app I'm developing, I turned off the drawing of the thumbnail completely, but still got the same lag.

Comment: maybe it is cause you use a debug build, debug builds are much slower and use twice the ram, switch to release and check how it goes.

Comment: I'll try that later today. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I made a release build, but no change. I did discover one other thing. In the app I'm developing (as opposed to the test app) when I drop a file the app displays an image. I discovered that I can drop a file _before_ the thumbnail, glyph, and text get displayed. The, after the same lag, the image gets displayed. That makes me think that all the messages are getting delayed - the dragOver message and the drop message. Then, 1/2 second later, all the messages get delivered and the app does what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DragOver` event is triggered when the application determines that the element under the current pointer is a potential placement target.

This requires the pointer to hover for a period of time. This may be the reason for the delay you think.

You can try the `DragEnter` event, which is triggered earlier than `DragOver`.

Thanks

Comment: That was interesting! I had tried DragEnter before in my main app and it gave NO reduction in the delay before the thumbnail/glyph/text appear so I wasn’t optimistic. However, I implemented it in my test app just to retest and added “DRAG ENTER message” to the text string I display. Sure enough, “DRAG ENTER message” appeared immediately, but then it still takes 1/2 second for the thumbnail/glyph/text to appear. Does that mean I have to live with that delay in UWP? I have apps previously, non-UWP apps, that don’t have this delay.

Comment: Hi, This part of the delay is the process of rebuilding the thumbnail of the picture, which cannot be skipped for now.

Comment: OK. That answers my question. Thank you @Richard !
As a postscript, I tried to give the user some earlier feedback by changing the opacity when the dragOver message arrives. However, the new opacity didn’t appear until the thumbnail/glyph/caption was displayed. Then I stopped the display of the thumbnail/glyph/caption by using e.DragUIOverride elements, but no luck. The opacity change is still delayed even though the none of the thumbnail/glyph/caption gets displayed.